# What is the purpose of the /run/shm directory?

Tags: linux

Shared Memory is created using shmget(2) and not with filesystem operations.
So what is the specific purpose of /run/shm as opposed to that of /run ?

Neither the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard FHS contains information about it, nor do the Ubuntu version of hier(7) or Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/run/shm` which was previously `/dev/shm` is temporary world-writable shared-memory. It is strictly intended as storage for programs using the POSIX Shared Memory API. Itmake possible inter-process communication (IPC), where different processes can share and communicate via a common memory area, which in this case is usually a normal file that is stored on a "ramdisk". Of course, it can be and has been used in other creative ways too.

Comment: A search for "POSIX Shared Memory API" reveals man 7 shm_overview. Citation from there: On  Linux,  shared memory objects are created in a (tmpfs) virtual filesystem, normally mounted under /dev/shm. ...  System V shared memory (shmget(2), shmop(2), etc.) is an older shared memory API.  POSIX shared memory provides a simpler, and better designed interface; on the other  hand  POSIX  shared memory is somewhat less widely available (especially on older systems) than System V shared memory.

Comment: This answer was essentially copied from http://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for without attribution.